# Is loading files with the jQuery CDN potentially dangerous?

Tags: jquery, security, cdn

My application is loading files from the jQuery CDN (code.jquery.com). I am wondering if that could cause any vulnerability or security gap for my application?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: This always comes down to how much you trust the CDN provider to do their job properly and serve you the right files. If someone could pull it off, compromising a CDN to serve hooky Javascript would have a very far reach indeed. It all comes down to your trust in their compentency. (i.e. an opinion)